# Лицензия на иконку

Tags: лицензирование, веб-программирование, html

Здравствуйте, наткнулся на такую вот иконку

[image: img]

и есть желание ее использовать для логотипа своей группы и сайта, изменив ее тем, что напишу на ней текст проекта. Если эта иконка будет на моем сайте и группе, даже если я буду получать с проекта деньги, но не буду продавать эту иконку, это не будет нарушать лицензию?

Answer (score 5):

Ну хоть один вопрос не от студентов на сессии и не от школьников)

На страничке, что вы указали написанно - "License -> Free for personal use only".

Если вы её напечатаете себе на футболку - это будет часный юз. Если на блоге на своем опубликуете - тоже.

Если же это будет основа для лого - то это уже не будет "для личного использования". Даже если вы не будете продавать "тыренное", а стырите лично для себя - это ведь все равно будет незаконно.

P.S. Если вы планируете зарабатывать на этом денежку, то думаю пару баксов на лого у вас найдется. Ну по крайней мере с первой прибыли)